# Notification with Remind letter functionality in desktop application vb.net

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I'm new bee to Desktop application in Vb.net. And i wanted to show the notification and it is having the remind me letter functionality so it will be show after 1 day(or else). 
So now I'm using the background worker to show the notification,But what should i use, to work with Remind me letter.
There are windows services but how to use it for showing notification,because services do not interact with UI component.

So How to work with Remind letter function.?

or what Else solution do you have...!

Thanks for any Help.

Comment: Do you mean like a pop-up in the bottom right hand corner?...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Dim notif As New NotifyIcon()
notif.Visible = True
notif.Icon = New Icon("C:\image1.ico")
notif.ShowBalloonTip(2000, "ALARM", "Remember to take your pills", ToolTipIcon.Info)
```

See [advanced use](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/903898/en-us) from MSDN.

Comment: Hi SysDragon Thanks,Actually i need solution for Remind me letter functionality. that should show me the notification after 1 day(or else xyz time).So the services are the best option or what else...i don't have any idea! Please help

Comment: @RahulShirphule I suppose you mean Redmine. Anyway, this answer was for your original question, as you said on your comment to Jacooobley. You changed your question drastically...

Comment: Sorry..!I thnink because of wrong Title question might change the direction.that's why i edited my question title.Okay thanks